# in my laravel application when i try to import data it's not working when that provider have more then 1000 service

Tags: laravel, database, insert

in my laravel application when i try to import data it's not working when that provider have more then 1000 service if it have under 1000 like 800 or 900 it insert my database but when it have 1500 or 2000 it loading 2 minute and service time out and not insert anything my database

i am shareing my code please let me know is there have any other method that insert lot;s of data in few second

```
public function apiServices($id)
{
    $page_title = 'API Services';
    $empty_message = 'No Result Found';
     

     
    $provider = Item::findOrFail($id);
    
    // echo   "$api";

    $userid= $provider->user_id;
    
   
   $apiLiveData = Curl::to($provider['apiurl'])
        ->withData(['key'=>$provider['apikey'], 'action'=>'services'])->post();
    $apiServicesData = json_decode($apiLiveData);
    $count =0;
    foreach($apiServicesData as $apiService):
        
        $services = Service::all();
       
        $existService = 0;
       
       
        foreach($services as $service):
            if($service->api_service_id == $apiService->service):
                $existService = 1;
            endif;
        endforeach;
        if($existService != 1):
            $service = new Service();
            
            $service->service_title = $apiService->name;
           
            $service->min_amount = $apiService->min;
            $service->max_amount = $apiService->max;
            $increased_price = ($apiService->rate/100)*10;
            $service->price = $apiService->rate+$increased_price;
            $service->service_status = 1;
            $service->api_provider_id = $id;
            $service->user_id = $userid;
            $service->api_service_id = $apiService->service;
            //$service->drip_feed = $apiService->dripfeed;
            $service->api_provider_price = $apiService->rate;
            $service->save();
        endif;
        $count++;
        // if($req['import_quantity']== 'all'):
        //     continue;
        // elseif($req['import_quantity']== $count):
        //     break;
        // endif;
    endforeach;
    
    return redirect()->back();

   // return view('backend.admin.services.show-api-services', compact('apiServiceLists','provider'));

    //return view('backend.admin.services.apiServices', compact('page_title', 'services', 'empty_message'));
}
```

Comment: Increase php time limit set_time_limit(600). But you should dispatch jobs with batches of 10 services for example. PS. Stop using endif. Use {}